# Laravel MongoDB 1:n relations

Tags: laravel, mongodb, relation

What is the correct way of defining 1:n relations in Laravel using MongoDB between two models `Author` and `Book` where one author can have several books while one book has exactly one authors?

Author.php

```
class Author extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        // what to place here?
        return $this->...
    }
}
```

Book.php

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        // what to place here?
        return $this->...
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function store (Author $author, Request $request)
    {
        $book1 Book::create();
        $book2 Book::create();

        // connect $book1 <-> $author and $book2 <-> $author
        // what to place here?

        $book1->save();
        $book2->save();
    }
}
```

After calling store() I want to be able to do the following request

```
dump ($book1->author); // return $author
dump ($author->books); // return Collection of $book1 and $book2
```

Comment: you only need the `case 2` here, it's 1-n

Comment: But I sometimes I need the request ```give me all instances of model_b which are are associated with a specific instance of model_a```. How can I do that with case 2?

Comment: can you provide more specification about the scenario or the query you want to achieve because the case you describe is what relationship is built for,

Comment: I want do define a relationship in laravel so I can use ```my_model_a->model_bs```. Of course I could construct a mongodb query doing this but I want to use the relationships of the laravel-mongodb package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume you have the foreign key `author_id` in `books` table

```
class Author extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class, 'author_id');
    }
}

class Book extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id');
    }
}

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function store (Author $author, Request $request)
    {
        $book1 = new Book();
        $book2 = new Book();

        $author->books()->saveMany([$book1, $book2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the ff:

```
users = model a
posts = model b

Case 1: vice versa of Case 2:

Case 2:
// on posts table/document you should have a user_id (as foreign key)
// and on post model you need define the belongsTo relationship
$this->belongsTo(User::class) 

// on the User model you have to define hasOne or hasMany
$this->hasOne(Post::class) or $this->hasMany(Post::class)

Case 3:
```

On case 3, I'm not sure if adding a reference to each other is necessary because creating a single reference that links them can provide the data you require regardless of whether the request comes from model a or model b.

It is possible that it will not solve your problem. However, hopefully it will be of some assistance to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is not what Im looking for. I want to retrieve the referencing models using the relation function of laravel. I dont want to write a separate for this.  
I updated my question with an example to make it more  clear.

Answer (score -1):

For case 1 ( in model_a ):

```
public function model_b_many()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Model_b::class, 'id' );
}
```

For case 2 ( in model_b ):

```
public function model_a_many()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Model_a::class, 'id' );
}
```

This will also work for case 3 :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working.  
For case 1 your solution creates a list 'id' in model_b referencing ids from model_a but I need the exactly opposite.